# PhoneStateListener returns null as incoming number

Tags: android, phone-state-listener

I am developing calls and sms blocking app, I have encountered the problem where I can't get incoming number from phonestatelistener. My code looks like this:

```
public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {

    switch (state) {
        case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE:



            break;
        case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK:

            break;
        case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:





            System.out.println("incoming number PhoneStateListener:" + incomingNumber);

                if (sBlockCall>0){
                    MuteAudio(getContext());
```

//reject call if number is matched to our blocking number

```
                    boolean callShouldBeBlocked = true;
                    for(int i = 0; i<sWhiteList.size(); i++){
                        if(sIncomingNumber.contains(sWhiteList.get(i).mNumber)){
                            UnMuteAudio(getContext());
                            System.out.println("CONTACT IS IN WHITE LIST");

                            callShouldBeBlocked = false;

                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    if(callShouldBeBlocked){
                        System.out.println("BLOCK CALL");
                        disconnectPhoneItelephony();

                    }


                } else {
                    UnMuteAudio(getContext());
                }

                //IT WORKS






            break;
    }
}
```

So my programm works not as I expect it to work, cause it always returns null as incoming number.

My manifest looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="oleksandr.ivanets.dontwakemeapp">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />

<application
    android:name=".MyApp"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>



    <receiver
        android:name=".PhoneStateReceiver"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:permission="android.permission.BROADCAST_SMS">
        <intent-filter android:priority="999999999">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
            <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>




</application>

   </manifest>
```

Comment: share your Menifest file, are permissions added and approved properly?

Comment: Have you registered your incoming call broadcast receiver in activity or manifest file?

Answer (score 1):

try adding this permissions, in my case this worked.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALL_LOG"/>
```